# How to assign Transform via code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i assign automatically the Transform via code using something like `GameObject.FindObjectOfType`?

[image]

Comment: No pain, no gain. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
raycastEnd = GameObject.Find("RaycastEnd").transform;
```

If you have multiple objects named "RaycastEnd" it will return the first one. `the first one` **may be unpredictable.**

Comment: Thanks, i was trying .FindObjectOfType and i was getting errors. It make sense now :)

Comment: @N1ckGreek GameObject.Find is slow, especially if used in update. Best is using tags and doing it in the start function [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html )